# PHP Associative Array Can't Seem To Use Variable As Index?

Tags: php, ajax, associative-array, wordpress

For some reason I can't use a variable as my index to an associative array?  $myarray["myindex"];.

Overview: I'm building a calendar schedule plugin that use WP Options API for use on a site.

The options set upon plugin initialization:

The jsn_event_list is all that matters and I've stripped the other elements of the array out for easy reading.  jsn_event_list is just an array of json objects related to specific events.

```
        $arr = array( "jsn_event_list" => '[{"date": "May 12, 2012", "type":"Breakfast","location":"Victoria"},{"date": "May 10, 2012", "type":"Breakfast","location":"Victoria"}, {"date": "May 7, 2012", "type":"Breakfast","location":"Victoria"}, {"date": "May 30, 2012", "type":"Breakfast","location":"Victoria"}, {"date": "May 29, 2012", "type":"Breakfast","location":"Victoria"}, {"date": "May 31, 2012", "type":"Breakfast","location":"Victoria"}]'
    );

    update_option('cal_sched_options', $arr);
```

Here's the function that receives a AJAX request to update the options from the plugins page:

```
function ajax_calendar_schedule_options() 
{
    // Get WP options
    $wp_plugin_option_name = 'cse_calendar_schedule_options';
    $wp_options = get_option($wp_plugin_option_name); // array of options listed above

    // Get post information
    $post = $_POST['data'];
    // EDITED LINE FROM:
    //$post_option_name = $post['option_name']; // HELP: option_name = string (13) "jsn_event_list" when var_dump($post['option_name']); BUT DOES NOT WORK WHEN $post_option_name IS USED TO INDEX BELOW ARRAYS
    // EDITED LINE TO:
    $post_option_name = "jsn_event_list"; // WORKS WHEN HARDCODED TO SAME VALUE AND USED IN BELOW ARRAYS TO INDEX 
    $post_option_value = $post['option_value']; // associative array = Array([date] => Mar 14, 2012, [type] => Dinner, [location] => Vancouver)

    // Get WP option using post option name
    $wp_option = $wp_options[$post_option_name];
    $wp_option = json_decode( $wp_option ); // array = Array([0] => stdClass Object( [date] => May 12, 2012, [type] => Breakfast, [location] => Victoria) ... etc )

    // Update by appending post as new array element
    $wp_option[] = $post_option_value;

    // Overwrite the changes with json string
    $wp_options[$post_option_name] = json_encode( $wp_option );

    // Save and sanitize (using cse_calendar_schedule_validate_options) changes
    update_option( $wp_plugin_option_name, $wp_options ); 

    // Return updated event list
    echo $wp_options[$post_option_name];

    die(); // Required to return a proper result
}
```

I know that using myarray[$myvar] works and I proved this by doing a quick two liner test but it doesn't work here... I tried casting (string) $post_option_name but nope.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure $post_option_name contains what you expect it to? Echo it to see what it dowes contain. Then var_dump( $wp_options) to see if this index does exist.

Comment: Even better, use `var_dump($post_option_name)` and examine the output very carefully to make sure it's not wrapped in an array or object.

Comment: I changed the original post code to use $post_option_name to index all arrays but only when it is hardcoded to the string I want.  Event though the string is passed and when var_dump($post_option_name) using posted value produces string (13) "jsn_event_list"

Comment: Iznogood you were right using var_dump is the way to go and then checking carefully.  Kijin you too it was yours that actually answered this for me since I could see later after some sleep it was spitting out "jsn_even_list" which is missing a "t" in "event" only really noticed this since I counted the length being (14) not (13).  Not sure who is right or actually how to mark one answer right over another.  Is this left up to the community? Either way thank you both.